# How to change volume gain in AOSP?

Tags: android, audio, android-source, hal, android-8.1-oreo

I need to change the volume gain of default speaker in my phone running on oreo. I have found some solution like mixer_path.xml but there are some values like

```
<ctl name="HPHL Volume" value="20" />
<ctl name="HPHR Volume" value="20" />
```

[please refer this link](https://github.com/SiXROM-OREO/device_moto_shamu/blob/oreo/mixer_paths.xml)

[please refer this second link for more idea](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NqfEpbhXfXyqRPJoLxtifbEMNCEuVOIokwT5kyjJ2KI/pub)

by setting this values can I able to change the gain of the speaker?
and also I want to know that what is the meaning of HPHL and HPHR(L stands for left and R is right what about HPH)?